# ords url parameter does not work

Tags: sql, oracle, rest, api, plsql

I am designing the ords api and encountered the following problem.

I would like to design the following api:

```
/ords/schema_name/customers/?name=somename
```

which could return the items where the column `customer_name` is equal to the input parameter `name`, if it is set on the url.

The ords service is defined:

```
BEGIN
   ORDS.DEFINE_SERVICE(
      p_module_name => 'customers' ,
      p_base_path   => '/customers/',
      p_pattern     => ':id?',
      p_source      => 'select * from customers where customer_id = nvl(:id,customer_id) and UPPER(customer_name) = nvl(UPPER(:name),UPPER(customer_name))'
   );

   COMMIT;
END;
```

However, the resonse I got from requesting `/ords/schema_name/customers/?name=somename` is as same as requesting `/ords/schema_name/customers/`. It returns all customers from database.

I have also tried sending request to `/ords/schema_name/customers?name=somename`.   Not luck also.

I would like to know why the parameters on url does not work and how to fix it.

Comment: I would try /ords/schema/customers?key=somekey. example of something similar here http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/03/a-tale-of-two-styles-of-uris-and-parameters-words/

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I have also tried sending request to ' /ords/schema_name/customers/?key=somekey'.   Not luck also.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith But I also see many examples on lines are doing '.../customers/?key=somekey'.

Comment: either do :var on the uri or do ?var=, don't do both

here's my module def
p_module_name    => 'richmond',
p_base_path      => '/richmond/',
p_pattern        => 'order'
p_source         => 'select c.*,
    cursor(
        select *
        from OE.ORDERS O
        where o.customer_id = c.customer_id)
       ORDERS
      from OE.CUSTOMERS c
         where c.customer_id = :id')

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I would like to put `id` into the url and regard some others as passed parameters. Because, I would also like to be able to search/query based on certain passed parameters.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith for example, in this example (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56351_01/doc.30/e56293/developing-REST-applications.htm#AELIG90176), `name` is designed in url, but `whom` is regarded as a passed parameter.

Comment: trading comments here sucks, send me an email with what you want jeff.d.smith@oracle.com. you CANT put the :id? as part of the pattern/url though. we handle the ? stuff automatically

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - rather than handing out your email address SO has a chat facility to handle these detailed sessions. [Check it out](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat)

Comment: i've used the chat, it gets annoying after 12 or 13 rounds of ping poing

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can query for ORDS.

1. **List:** `http://<server>:<port>/ords/scott/emp`
2. **Get by Pk:** `http://<server>:<port>/ords/scott/emp/7788`
3. **Sorting:**
   `http://<server>:<port>/ords/scott/emp?q={"$orderby":{"ENAME":"ASC"}}
   http://<server>:<port>/ords/scott/emp?q={"$orderby":"SAL":"DESC","ENAME":"ASC"}}`
4. **Filtering:**

   > ```
   > http://<server>:<port>/ords/scott/emp?q={"SAL":5000}
   > http://<server>:<port>/ords/scott/emp?q={"SAL":{"$eq":5000}}
   > ```

**Note:** If you are using the `ORDS` advanced mode installation ie. using separate `Tomcat` server for running the ORDS server then you have to be aware of the tomcat version. The latest version of the tomcat[`apache-tomcat-8.5.11,apache-tomcat-8.0.39`] does support the query parameter but you have to pass the encoded format, not the plain.

To encode, you can just use **encodeURIComponent()** javascript function:

```
encodeURIComponent('{"field_name": "<value>"}')
```

Likewise, the `apache-tomcat-8.0.30` which supports plain query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare and define the parameters:
I don't see any parameter definition in your PL/SQL code.
You have to call ORDS.DEFINE_PARAMETER.